# Potential function of $F(x, y)=\left(\lambda x-x^3, y\right)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE: $$x''=\lambda x-x^3$$
To work with it, I turned it into a system of equations:
$$\begin{matrix}
x' & = & y \\
y' & = & \lambda x -x^3
\end{matrix}$$
Now I want to find a first integral for this system, as well as a potential function for $F(x, y)=\left(\lambda x-x^3, y\right)$. To find the first integral I've done:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\lambda x-x^3}{y} \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \frac{y^2}{2}=\lambda \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{4} +C$$
Therefore the first integral is:
$$E(x,y)=y^2-\lambda x^2+\frac{x^4}{2}$$
I've tried calculating the potential function but I got the exact same result, and I don't think this is correct. Can someone help me with the potential? Thank you in advance

Comment: You seem to be using the non-fact that $\int x\,dx=x$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich it was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a separable situation like the present, then the connection between first integral/Hamiltonian/energy and the potential is
$$
H(x,y)=\frac12y^2+P(x)
$$
So in this case you can chose $P(x)=\frac14(x^2-λ)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

There was two mistakes in the equation :
$$y^2=\lambda x^\color{red}{2}-\frac{x^4}{\color{red}{2}  }+C$$
( Corrected in red ).

Then :
$$y=x'=\pm \sqrt{\lambda x-\frac{x^4}{2}+C}$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\pm \sqrt{\lambda x-\frac{x^4}{2  }+C}$$
$$t(x)=\pm \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\lambda x^2-\frac{x^4}{2  }+C}}$$
This is an elliptic integral.

The inverse function $x(t)$ involves the Jacobi elliptic functions.

Comment: Is $t(x)$ the potential? I am not sure I understand your answer